# Using an XML Schema Definition to export data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd

From one of our partners I got some XML Schema definition files (*.xsd).

are there any good tutorials on how to use visual studio to generate an XML file using the xsd file with the data from our databases.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate some c# classes from the schema and then performm some kind of data mapping operation to extract the data from you db and map into these classes.

To generate the classes you can use the [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe). An example of this might be as simple as:

```
xsd /classes Schema.xsd
```

See [XML Schema Definition Tool Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe#examples) for further examples usage.

Once you have these classes you can extract the data from your database, map to these classes and then serialize to xml using something like the below:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

 using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
 using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
 {
     ser.Serialize(writer, myObject);
     string xml = sw.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft's [XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to generate C# classes, populate the classes and then use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class to serialize the objects to XML.

There are plenty of tutorials for both using xsd.exe and `XmlSerializer`. Google it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate classes for the xsd file with xsd.exe, and then serialize those classes to xml files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

"Generates runtime classes from an XSD schema file. The generated classes can be used in conjunction with System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer to read and write XML code that follows the schema."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx